# How to only get set members of a class in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I Have a class like this:

```
public class Products
{


    public string name {get; set;}
    public string CustomName {get; set;}

}
```

and then I create this:

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
```

And then do this using JSON.Net

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

What i want to happen is if a custom name is not set like `product.Customname = "CustomApple";` not to display in the JSON because right now if its not set it still shows up as `'CustomName': 'null'` but if its not i don't want it to show up at all only to display set properties like product.Name

I tried changing it to private but can't set it anymore

```
 public class Products
    {


    public private name {get; set;}
    public private CustomName {get; set;}

}
```

how could i do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using JsonSerializerSettings.

```
     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, new JsonSerializerSettings
     {
         NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
     });
```

If you want only the specified variables to be not presented if null then use:

```
public class Products
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string name {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CustomName {get; set;}
}
```